# Newbie here! When using a method of one class inside a method of another class, do I have to pass the self argument as well

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am trying to write test script . This is my code.

```
class baseclass():

   def __init__(self, driver):
       self.driver=driver

   def click_on(self, what):
       self.driver.find_element(*what).click()

class initialpage(baseclass):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def click_mailbtn(self):
        baseclass.click_on(locators.mail_icon_xpath)
```

when i run the test in pytest it gives me an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znJKy.jpg)

```
TypeError: click_on() missing 1 required positional argument: 'what'
```

when i pass the self argument in the code as below, it works fine

```
def click_mailbtn(self):
        baseclass.click_on(**self**, locators.mail_icon_xpath)
```

is it necessary to pass self argument in this case ? or am I doing something wrong here ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `initialpage` inherits from `baseclass`, you would typically call `click_on` like so:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver        

    def click_on(self, what):
        self.driver.find_element(*what).click()

class InitialPage(Base):

    def click_mail_btn(self):
        self.click_on(locators.mail_icon_xpath)
```

I suggest reading [the Python documentation on inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) for more details on what is actually happening here and why inherited methods are called like this.